# Sort issues with TArray<Myrectype> for large numbers

Tags: arrays, sorting, delphi

What is the reason why `TArray.Sort<Mytype>` does not work when I have large numbers in the comparison?

My code is as follows (Delphiy Tokyo):

```
Interface

Type 
 RCInd = record
           Num              : Integer;
           Ger              : Integer;           
           Confirmed        : Boolean;
           Total            : Real;
   End;

   TArrInd = TArray<RCInd>;

   Procedure SortInd  (Var PArrayInd  : TArrInd);

Implementation  

Procedure SortInd  (Var PArrayInd  : TArrInd);    
begin
  TArray.Sort<RCInd>( PArrayInd,TComparer<RCInd>.Construct
                       ( function (Const Rec1, Rec2 : RCInd) : Integer 
                         begin
                           Result := - ( Trunc(Rec1.Total) - Trunc(Rec2.Total) );
                         end )
                       );
end;

......
```

When the values of Rec1.Total  and Rec2.Total are within a Integer limits, this Sort works fine, BUT when values exceed Integer limits Sort procedure does not work!   It generates a non sorted set of data in PArrayInd .

What is going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is one of overflow. The real values overflow the integer type.

The compare function is meant to return negative to indicate less than, positive to. Indicate greater than and zero to indicate equal. Your using arithmetic is the cause of your problem, leading as it does to overflow. Instead use comparison operators.

```
function(const Rec1, Rec2: RCInd): Integer
begin
  if Rec1.Total < Rec2.Total then
    Result := 1
  else if Rec1.Total > Rec2.Total then
    Result := -1
  else
    Result := 0;
end;
```

---

The problem in this question is trying to fit a real value into an integer, but even if you have integer data then arithmetic should not be used for compare functions. Consider the expression

```
Low(Integer) - 1
```

This results in overflow. As a general principle, always use comparison operators to implement compare functions.

Comment: that is it !  I changed the function as you proposed and it worked !  Thanks a lot !